# SAR instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I need help understanding what I am doing wrong. I am using emu8086 assembler to check my answer. Here is the code.

```
MOV AL, 11001111b ;CFh
SAR AL, 1
NOP
```

So, I know that I am suppose to replace the highest bit with 0 and shift to the right. The lowest bit is copied into the carry flag.

My AL after the SAR instruction, I got 01100111b or 67h
When I used the emulator to check my answer, I receive E7h as my answer. Can anyone help me figure out my mistake?

Comment: Read your processor manual again. SAR does not change the highest bit.

Comment: oh, you're right. thank you. So, with that information I should get 1110 0111

Comment: SAR does *arithmetic* shift, which pads the sign bit into shifted positions. SHL will do a logic shift

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oh no! So close - you meant to write `SHR`